# Exchange of objects (or message) between AsyncTasks already started

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opencv, android-asynctask

I have three AsyncTask: The first captures the image frame (more than one per second) Mat type and should pass it to the second AsyncTask. The second processes the frame and if it is necessary it should communicate the third AsyncTask to take the picture.

How can I manage the communication between AsyncTasks already started  My idea was to use static objects but it does not seem like an "elegant" solution.

PS: It would be better if they communicated with objects, but I also accept tips on how to communicate simple messages.

Thank you

Comment: I guess you must have some "global shared space" between the tasks where you can place messages `(information: sender, receiver, content)` and each task reads those messages during the tasks. Another way would be to use some callback function lists (each task gets a list of callback functions for each other task). Not sure whether AsyncTask already provides some kind of communication. Each method has advantages and disadvantages. This link says you can use `Handler` to communicate between tasks: http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1780660/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach has several problems that can prove to be hard to tackle:

1) Mat objects are quite expensive in terms of memory and allocation time, so if you capture several frames per second and keep them in memory while the AsyncTask runs you can end up with OutOfMemory exceptions;

2) On some Android versions all AsyncTasks run on the same thread, meaning that they will actually work sequentially. On the best case scenario there is a thread pool used for running AsyncTasks, meaning you will have a finite number of running tasks.

I would suggest you do all your processing inside `onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)`. But i guess you already tried that and the processing time is to big to display a preview that has sufficient FPS.

To strictly answer your question, you could use an event bus communication system for the AsyncTasks. I have used Otto, and it is quite easy to setup and there are plenty of examples(http://square.github.io/otto/). This is a very good example of using Otto (http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/). Just make sure you create a separate class file for each tasks response or you'll get tasks consuming each other's messages.

However, if you want to continue with your approach I would suggest you use threads and intercommunication. There are plenty of simple examples around.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently the entire process of image analysis is performed inside onCameraFrame (CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 1.6 FPS (really low, and the software is tested on a S4). The idea was to separate the various phases in separate threads, but I think the best idea is to use only one thread to acquire the photos and leave everything else inside onCameraFrame (CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) because in any case the second thread (the one that deals with the analysis of the image) would work always at that speed (1.6 FPS). My idea is correct?

Comment: The correct way is to process everything inside onCameraFrame, because the processing thread must always have the current displayed frame, and not a frame that was taken 1-2 seconds before. You could try to fine tune your algorithm to achieve better speeds. BTW, I am using OpenCV with some edge detection algorithms, and on a S4 the frame rate is terrible(1-2 FPS), but on a Nexus 4 and 5 the frame rate boosts to around 10 FPS.